# Drawing Circle programmatically using Android ShapeDrawable

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable, xml-drawable, shapedrawable

I have a requirement in my project to draw a circle in runtime dynamically. So for that purpose I am using ShapeDrawable to create circle programmatically, but unfortunately I could not find any class or methods inside ShapeDrawable for CircleShape, instead I found only `OvalShape()`. So kindly please help me to draw a circle through ShapeDrawable by just passing diameter or radius of the circle. Thanks in advance. Any kind of customization would be useful for me to fix my solution.

Code I am using for ShapeDrawable is

```
public static ShapeDrawable drawCircle (Context context, int width, int height, int color) {

        //////Drawing oval & Circle programmatically /////////////

        ShapeDrawable oval = new ShapeDrawable (new OvalShape ());
        oval.setIntrinsicHeight (height);
        oval.setIntrinsicWidth (width);
        oval.getPaint ().setColor (color);
        return oval;
    }
```

Code using in `MainActivity.java`

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            txtCount.setBackground (Util.drawCircle (MainActivity.this, 50, 50, getResources ().getColor (R.color.yellow)));
            txtHotelCount.setText ("20");
        }else{
            txtCount.setBackgroundDrawable (Util.drawCircle (MainActivity.this, 50, 50, getResources ().getColor (R.color.yellow)));
            txtHotelCount.setText ("20");

        }
```

xml using for **TextView** `txtCount` in my project for is

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text_grey"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text_grey"
            android:text="AVAILABLE"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

But still no luck even after setting the same width and height as 50. The property is behaving still like oval.

Comment: if `width == height` then the Oval should be a Circle ?

Comment: But I am not getting a circle. For example if I pass width as 42 and height as 23, I am getting circle.

Comment: Show the code that uses this ShapeDrawable. What is the size of the View that uses it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Give same height and width to your `TextView`

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_count"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textColor="@color/text_grey"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            />
```

Comment: whats the parents of 'txtCount'  ?

Comment: You should give a same height and width to your Textview

Comment: Thanks it worked! Really helpful to rectify my silly mistake in xml. I accept this solution

Answer (score 9):

This is too late to answer but hope it will help someone else. If want to draw circle like this, dont bother with 46.0% as it is only text view.

[image].

```
public class Circle extends View {

private Paint mCircleYellow;
private Paint mCircleGray;

private float mRadius;
private RectF mArcBounds = new RectF();

public Circle(Context context) {
    super(context);

    // create the Paint and set its color

}

public Circle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    initPaints();
}

public Circle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

private void initPaints() {
    mCircleYellow = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mCircleYellow.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mCircleYellow.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    mCircleYellow.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mCircleYellow.setStrokeWidth(15 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    mCircleYellow.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.SQUARE);
    // mEyeAndMouthPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    mCircleYellow.setColor(Color.parseColor("#F9A61A"));

    mCircleGray = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mCircleGray.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mCircleGray.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    mCircleGray.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mCircleGray.setStrokeWidth(15 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    mCircleGray.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.SQUARE);
    // mEyeAndMouthPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    mCircleGray.setColor(Color.parseColor("#76787a"));

}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    mRadius = Math.min(w, h) / 2f;

}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int h = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int size = Math.min(w, h);
    setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Float drawUpto = 46f;


    float mouthInset = mRadius / 3f;
    mArcBounds.set(mouthInset, mouthInset, mRadius * 2 - mouthInset, mRadius * 2 - mouthInset);
    canvas.drawArc(mArcBounds, 0f, 360f, false, mCircleGray);

    canvas.drawArc(mArcBounds, 270f, drawUpto, false, mCircleYellow);


}
```

}

So use this class in your xml file as it is a view class.

Answer (score -3):

```
 // Circle

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    float x = 50;
    float y = 50;
    float radius = 20;
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
```